# Temporally synchronize two iOS devices over Multipeer Connectivity in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, synchronization, multipeer-connectivity, temporal

I would like to temporally synchronize two iOS devices using Multipeer Connectivity (so it should work for both WIFI and Bluetooth) in Swift.

Ideally, I would need a synchronisation within 0.03 ms, but 0.3 ms would be acceptable.

So far, I am playing a sound from device 1 and record it with device 2, measuring the time from the moment when the devices are connected with each other over Multipeer Connectivity.

Unfortunately, this does not provide the accurate temporal synchronization needed for my application.

Answer (score 0):

Just send the current time from one device and then compare it on the other side when the message is received.

Preparing message:

```
// this is the value to send    
let date = NSDate()
```

On the message received code:

```
let interval = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceDate(theDate)
```

That interval is the time passed since the initial date was created on the other device.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But if I understood it well, A sends it timing to B, which receives it after t. But it does not tell me how to synchronize A and B. So if time of A is 100 and time of B is 200 for instance, and t takes 20 to be transmitted from A to B, B will receive 100 at 220, but it does not provide me with information on synchronizing both devices, does it?

Comment: Use `playAtTime:`, a method/function belonging to AVAudioPlayer. Without info about your audio playback, I'm assuming you're using that default audio player implementation. `playAtTime:` takes an NSTimeInterval as parameter, so it's perfect for use with your created interval variable.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. So, if I follow you, A sends its time (100) to B (200), which he receives at 220 for instance, and can ask to play something at time 220 + delay. But still, how do we know the time between A sending the message and B receiving it? So 20 in our case?

Comment: Hi Chris, I am still struggling to synchronize temporally two iOS devices, even with the method you suggested earlier. It looks like there is always a latency in the function playAtTime. Any idea to get a more accurate temporal synchronization?